# How to count linked entries in another table with a specific value

Tags: sql, join

Let's say I have two tables. A students table and an observations table. If the students table looks like:

```
Id Student Grade
1  Alex    3
2  Barney  3
3  Cara    4
4  Diana   4
```

And the observations table looks like:

```
Id Student_Id Observation_Type
1  1          A
2  1          B       
3  3          A
4  2          A
5  4          B
6  3          A
7  2          B
8  4          B
9  1          A
```

Basically, the result I'd like from the query would be the following:

```
Student Grade Observation_A_Count
Alex    3     2
Barney  3     1
Cara    4     2
Diana   4     0
```

In other words, I'd like to gather data for each student from the students table and for each student count the number of A observations from the observations table and tack that onto the other information. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: You should always specify which database you're using as SQL dialects differ, and you should also be sure to tag your question as homework when you're doing an assignment and not asking a real world question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a simple join and aggregate:

```
select
  a.Student,
  a.Grade,
  count(b.Id) as Observation_A_Count
from
  Student a left join
  Observations b on a.Id = b.Student_Id
group by
  a.Student,
  a.Grade
order by
  1
```

Or, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select
  a.Student,
  a.Grade,
  (select count(*) from observations x where x.Student_Id = a.Id) as Observation_A_Count
from
  Student a
order by
  a.Student
```

Answer (score 2):

You can join the table with a specific condition, by doing this you can have a field for Observation_B_Count and Observation_C_Count, etc.

```
SELECT Student.Student, Student.Grade, COUNT(Observation_Type.*) AS Observation_A_Count
FROM Student
LEFT JOIN Observations ON Observations.Student_ID = Student.Student_ID AND Observations.Observation_Type = 'A'
GROUP BY Student.Student, Student.Grade
```